# Join 2 multidimensional arrays php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have 2 multidimensionals arrays

eg:

```
$data[0] = "value1, value2, value3, value4, value5";

$data[1] = "name1, name2, name3, name4, name5";
```

how can i join them together so that each value in `data[0]` takes the name from `data[1]`
output should be foreach value:

```
$newarray[0] = Array('value'=>'value1', 'name'=>'name1'); 
$newarray[1] = Array('value'=>'value2', 'name'=>'name2');
```

and so on

Thanx ;)

Comment: I can't see multidimensional arrays in your sample, just a array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I may have misunderstood your question, but if I understand it correctly then something like this should do it:

```
$values = preg_split('/,\s+/', $data[0]);
$names  = preg_split('/,\s+/', $data[1]);

$length = min(count($values), count($names));
$newarray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $newarray[] = array(
        'value' => array_shift($values),
        'name' => array_shift($names),
    );
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer, but, really i can't see where are the multidimensional arrays in his sample.

Comment: @GonzaloBahamondez What do you mean? I am assuming that `$data[0]` and `$data[1]` exist somewhere, like in the questioner's example.

Comment: I meant, $data is a array of strings not a multidimensional array, but well your assumption was correct.

Comment: @GonzaloBahamondez The OP has provided the data for the array through some strings in `data[0]` and `data[1]`, and the answerer split them using `preg_split()` (this also could have been done through `explode()`) and then the rest of story...